# Detailed info about VPN in use

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, protocols, vpn

I think I am missing something, because I only find VPN protocol info (my main interest) in a separate list from all the other info. For showing VPN info, I found 3 cmd commands useful:

```
ipconfig /all
netsh interface ip show config
netstat
```

Only at the bottom of `netstat` list I see the element `vpn:pptp` which clearly tells the protocol that's in use.

Maybe there is a cmd/PowerShell command which can show VPN info in one place?

Comment: What info do you mean ?

Comment: Protocols in use, IPs, settings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Get-VPNConnection cmdlet?
You can find more info about the cmdlet with

```
get-help get-VPNConnection
```

is it helpful?

Comment: It seems that `Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection` states settings, but not specifically what's in use. In my case `TunnelType : Pptp`, it's fine, but I find that it can yield `Automatic`, which seems like a setting, but not an actual protocol. Also, `ConnectionStatus : Disconnected`, which is confusing, because I am connected to the VPN.

Comment: Well I don't know if you can get all the information from one cmdlet. to get IP Address and type for example you can use the Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias "<interface name>", to see the source address and the interface you use you can use the Test-NetConnection -TraceRoute <destination> . its all depend on what you want to see. you can easily combine them all in a script or in a custom object.

Comment: Get-VpnConnection appears to require Windows 10+ or Server 2012+. I do not find it on Windows 7 or Server 2008.